# How can you find the lowest unused (ID) number in an array whose objects may have any ID number?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to find the lowest *unused* ID number for a Book object.  The Book objects may have any ID number greater than 0, in no particular order (i.e. 1, 6, 0, 4 is entirely possible).  What I have so far is below, which I am reasonably sure will do as specified.  I am, however, uncertain, thus this question.  My code is below.

```
    public int findUseableBookNumber(ArrayList<Book> list){
    int testnum = 0;
    int iter;
    boolean didFindNumber = false;
    while(!didFindNumber){
        iter = 0;
        for(Book book: list){
            if(book.getBookNumber() == testnum){
                testnum++;
                break;
            }
            else iter++;
        }
        //If you have gone through the entire list?
        if(iter == list.size()) didFindNumber = true;
    }
    return testnum;
}
```

Did I do this correctly?

If not, what did I do wrong?

Comment: Since you know what the code sbould do you can easily test it. Call the method with differently filled lists and see if the returned value is correct. You might want to look up what "unit testing" is and how it works in Java.

Comment: Darn, I was hoping someone wouldn't say that.  I have to do a lot of typing to get those lists all set up.

Comment: Are you serious? Because we totally should not test our own code but ask strangers in the internet...